# Automation Script in maximo, how to count days between 2 dates without weekends and holidays?

Tags: jython, maximo

Automation Script in maximo, how to count days between 2 dates without weekends and holidays?
I could count days, and remove Sundays and Saturdays but what about holidays?
In Maximo present calendar application where all holidays is present. How I could use it with jython scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I made it. Maximo has table "nonworktime" it contain all holidays from calendar application.
So, i write this jython script for automation Script in maximo. It return number of working days between 2 dates.

```
#********************* 
def getDateDiff(start, finish):
    calStart=0
    calStart=Calendar.getInstance()
    calStart.setTime(start)
    calFinish=0
    calFinish=Calendar.getInstance()
    calFinish.setTime(finish)
    daysDiff=0 
    str1=str(0)
    cS=None    
    if calStart.getTime()<calFinish.getTime():
        while calStart.getTime()<=calFinish.getTime():        
            if calStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) !=1 and calStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) !=7:
                cS = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(calStart.getTime())            
                myMXServer = MXServer.getMXServer()
                userInfo = mbo.getThisMboSet().getUserInfo()
                nwSet= myMXServer.getMboSet("NONWORKTIME", userInfo)
                nwSetWhere = 'to_date( \''+cS+'\' , \'dd.mm.yyyy\' ) >= startdate and to_date(\''+cS+'\' , \'dd.mm.yyyy\' ) <=enddate'
                nwSet.setWhere(nwSetWhere)
                nwSet.reset()
                if nwSet.count() ==0:
                    daysDiff = daysDiff+1
            calStart.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)     
    else:
        while calFinish.getTime()<=calStart.getTime():        
            if calFinish.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) !=1 and calFinish.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) !=7:
                cS = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(calFinish.getTime())            
                myMXServer = MXServer.getMXServer()
                userInfo = mbo.getThisMboSet().getUserInfo()
                nwSet= myMXServer.getMboSet("NONWORKTIME", userInfo)
                nwSetWhere = 'to_date( \''+cS+'\' , \'dd.mm.yyyy\' ) >= startdate and to_date(\''+cS+'\' , \'dd.mm.yyyy\' ) <=enddate'
                nwSet.setWhere(nwSetWhere)
                nwSet.reset()
                if nwSet.count() ==0:
                    daysDiff = daysDiff-1
            calFinish.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)         
    return str(daysDiff)
#**********************
daysDiffernce = getDateDiff(plandate, factdate)
```